How to Process Files in N8n Using Python-Node?
I want to create an automation in N8n (in the cloud) that triggers whenever a new Google Sheets or Excel file is uploaded to Google Drive. The goal is to:
Access the file in Python (e.g., read columns, make changes like dividing values, etc.).
Save the modified file and re-upload it to Google Drive.
Locally, I would use a simple Python script like this:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
df['B'] = df['A'] / 2
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)

How can I achieve a similar process in N8n? If Python isn't possible, would a JavaScript node work instead?
Any help or examples would be appreciated!
